# Can't convert DateTime to ReadableInstant using Joda time

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I want to find the number of years between two dates. I wrote simple test case to check that.

```
@Test
public void testGetYears() {
    DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1,0,0,0,0);
    DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2016,2,1,0,0,0,0);
    Days.daysBetween(oldDate, newDate).getDays(); //this line works
    Years.yearsBetween(oldDate, newDate).getYears(); //no suitable method found
    assertEquals(2, Years.yearsBetween(oldDate, newDate).getYears());
}
```

Error:

```
Error:(146, 14) java: no suitable method found for yearsBetween(org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime,org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime)
method org.joda.time.Years.yearsBetween(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,org.joda.time.ReadableInstant) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime cannot be converted to org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)
method org.joda.time.Years.yearsBetween(org.joda.time.ReadablePartial,org.joda.time.ReadablePartial) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime cannot be converted to org.joda.time.ReadablePartial)
```

I have look into the yearsBetween definition is requires same parameter as in daysBetween function. So I am wondring why it does not work for yearsBetween.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try and use `DateTime` as provided by elasticsearch (`org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.DateTime`) with the `Years` class of joda-time itself (`org.joda.time.Years`).

Either use joda-time classes everywhere or elasticsearch provided joda-time classes; but not both at the same time!

Comment: Oh I see. Years is not part of elastic version's of joda time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) for that:

```
DateTime oldDate = new DateTime(2014,1,1,0,0,0,0);
DateTime newDate = new DateTime(2016,2,1,0,0,0,0);
Period p = new Period(oldDate, newDate);
int years = p.getYears();
```

retrieves the years between the two dates.